# how to use angular oboe without "oboe is not defined"

Tags: angularjs

I want to use "angular oboe"  for http requests so returning very large json. I included the library and put a function in my controller, but I get "Error: oboe is undefined". I dont know if I miss to include other libreía or that may be the problem.

My Code

```js
var app = angular.module('dataview', ['ngOboe'])
app.controller('DataViewCtrl', function($scope, Oboe){
     $scope.oboeget = function(uri)
    {
        //in uri i pass url so retun json
        $scope.data = [];

        Oboe({
            url: uri,
            pattern: '{timestamp}', 
            start: function(stream) {
                $scope.stream = stream;
                $scope.status = 'reading....';
            },
            done: function() {
                $scope.status = 'done';
            }
        }).then(function() {
            // not used
        }, function(error) {
            // some error
        }, function(record) {
            $scope.data.push(record);
        });
    }

}
```

```html
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-oboe/dist/angular-oboe.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I notice in your error, oboe is lowercase, but in code it's uppercase.  Did you type the error by hand and maybe change the case, or is that the same case as the error?

Answer (score 2):

You need to include Oboe before Angular-Oboe.

```
<script src="/bower_components/oboe/dist/oboe-browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-oboe/dist/angular-oboe.min.js"></script>
```

I created a pull request to update the documentation :
https://github.com/RonB/angular-oboe/pull/8